# Can't access RTC Alarm Registers for second time

Tags: stm32, rtc

Hi STM32F103 Programmers

I am fighting with my RTC. I have it working but have problems with accessing the Alarm registers for the second time. I can't find the reason why I can't.

I program the RTC direct using Bit fields and when needed register bit shift operations That works quite well till now and I do it on various peripherals without a problem. I have mapped all peripherals on structs with uint32_t members and assigned all bits to these registers.

I develop this code on the VSC for the STM32F103.

The code for configuring the RTC is working, It accesses the CNT and the ALR registers with no problem. All bits to access the RTC are configured DBP, RTOFF, RTCEN....... This is the code

```
void  RTC_Config() {
    RCC_PRB       *PRCC  = (RCC_PRB*)RCC_BASE;          // Map the Periferals structs to the addresses of the periferals  
    PWR_PRB       *PPWR  = (PWR_PRB*)PWR_BASE;
    RTC_PRB       *PRTC  = (RTC_PRB*)RTC_BASE;
    NVIC_PRB      *PNVIC = (NVIC_PRB*)NVIC_BASE;
    BKP_PRB       *PBKP  = (BKP_PRB*)BKP_BASE;
     
    uint32_t       PRL_Div, TRclk, RTclk=1;   // RTclk=1sec
     
    //__NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
    //PNVIC->ISER0.RTC_IRQ       = 0x01;                   // Enable global RTC_IRQn;
    //PNVIC->IPR0.RTC_PRI        = 0x01;                   // Set the RTC_IRQn Interupt priority
    //PNVIC->ISER1.RTC_Alarm_IRQ = 0x01;                 // Enable RTC_ALARM_IRQ;
    //NVIC_SetPriority (RTC_IRQn, 10);
    //NVIC_EnableIRQ(RTC_IRQn);
    //RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_BKPEN;
     
    PRCC->APB1ENR.PWREN= 0x01;                           // Enable clock PWR register block
    PRCC->APB1ENR.BKPEN= 0x01;                           // Enable clock backup Register block
    PPWR->CR.DBP       = 0x01;                           // Disable backup domain write protection DBP=1
    PRCC->BDCR.RTCEN   = 0x01;                           // Enable the RTC Clock
     
    STM32_Config(); 
    PBKP->RTCCR.CAL    = 0x00;                           // Calibrate RC Oscilator if needed;
    PRCC->BDCR.LSEON   = 0x01;                           // Enable LSE Clock 
    while (PRCC->BDCR.LSERDY==0x00);                     // Readonly flag, LSEBYP=1 LSE clock is ready
    PRCC->BDCR.RTCSEL  = 0x01;                           // set clock as LSE 32.768 kHz, Ones selected RTCEL is locked.
    PRTC->CRL.RSF      = 0x00;                           // Clear RSF Registers Synchronized Flag bit by writing a zero.
    while( PRTC->CRL.RSF == 0x00) delay(1);              // test RSflag=1, at low LSE frequencies 50hz it can take up to a minute.  Weird delay(1) is needed otherwise it hangs
    //while( (RTC->CRL & RTC_CRL_RSF) == 0x00);          // test RSflag=1, at low LSE frequencies 50hz it can take up to a minute.  Weird works without delay(1)
     
    while( PRTC->CRL.RTOFF==0x00);                       // All registers are loaded RTOFF=1
    PRTC->CRL.CNF      = 0x01;                           // Enter Configuration Mode CNF=1
    //PRTC->CRH.SECIE    = 0x01;                           // Enable second Interupt;
    //PRTC->CRH.ALRIE    = 0x01;                           // Enable Alarm Interupt;
     
    switch(PRCC->BDCR.RTCSEL) {
      case 0b00 : { TRclk=0;           } break;          // No Clock selected
      case 0b01 : { TRclk=32768;       } break;          // TRclk=extrenal LS Xtal value
      case 0b10 : { TRclk=40000;       } break;          // Uncalibrated RC clock value. Calibration possible.
      case 0b11 : { TRclk=HSE_VALUE>>7;} break;          // TRclk=HSE/128 = 8E6/128 = 62500
      default   : {} ;
    }
    PRL_Div= (uint32_t)(((float)TRclk/(float)RTclk)+0.5);  
    PRTC->PRLH.PRL     = (PRL_Div-1)>>16;                 // High bits [19:16], PRLvalue = Div-1
    PRTC->PRLL.PRL     = (PRL_Div-1) & 0xFFFF;            // Low bits  [15:00], PRLvalue = Div-1
    PRTC->CNTH.CNT     = 0x0023;                          // Load CNTH with current EPOCH value otr 0x00
    PRTC->CNTL.CNT     = 0xFFF8;                          // Load CNTL with current EPOCH value otr 0x00
    PRTC->ALRH.ALR     = 0x0024;                          // Set the Alarm Flag High
    PRTC->ALRL.ALR     = 0x0005;                          // Set the Alarm Flag Low
    delay(1);
    PRTC->CRL.CNF      = 0x00;                            // Leave the Configuration Mode, Write registyer Cycle starts
    while( PRTC->CRL.RTOFF==0x00);                        // Test if All registers are loaded RTOFF=1 
}
```

I also have an interrupt routine which I don't use as an interrupt routine yet. I call it from the main loop. All RTC related interrupt masks are off.

```
void RTC_IRQHandler(void) { 
    RTC_PRB       *PRTC  = (RTC_PRB*)RTC_BASE;
    PWR_PRB       *PPWR  = (PWR_PRB*)PWR_BASE;
    if( PRTC->CRL.SECF==0x01) { PRTC->CRL.SECF=0x00;  printf("S."); } 
    if( PRTC->CRL.ALRF==0x01) { 
        PRTC->CRL.ALRF=0x00;  
        printf("A%u.", PPWR->CR.DBP);
        while( PRTC->CRL.RTOFF==0x00);
          
        PRTC->CRL.CNF      = 0x01;
        PRTC->ALRH.ALR     = 0x0024;                          // Set the Alarm Flag High
        PRTC->ALRL.ALR     = 0x0020;
        PRTC->CRL.CNF      = 0x00;
        delay(1); 
        while( PRTC->CRL.RTOFF==0x00);   
    }     // Reset the Sec Interrupt flag
    if( PRTC->CRL.OWF ==0x01) { PRTC->CRL.OWF =0x00;  printf("O."); }
    while( PRTC->CRL.RTOFF==0x00);                
}
```

I can read access the CNT and ALM and CR registers with no problem. The CNT is counting up per second. When the alarm goes off and it does, this Int routine is called and it should config the alarms to a new value. It doesn't do that. I have no idea why. I tested access to the alarm registers in other ways but with no success.

Can anyone help me why I can't access my alarm registers for the second and third..... time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your interrupt routine must be run when there is an alarm interrupt, or when the SECF bit is set in the RTC Control Register. Only then can you write to the RTC alarm register.

Look in the below images from the manual:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Just letting you know so that you don't keep trying to call it manually and pull hairs.

You also have a couple:

```
while( PRTC->CRL.RTOFF==0x00);
```

at the end that aren't necessary.

Also, (and possibly most importantly) I would put the printf statements outside of the interrupt. Just use a few booleans and make them true when an interrupt happens. I learned that the hard way.

```
if( PRTC->CRL.OWF ==0x01) { PRTC->CRL.OWF =0x00;  overflow_bool = true; }

loop(){
...
    if(overflow_bool){
        printf("O.");
        overflow_bool=false;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Great help Andrew thanks.  
That text from the STM32 specification doc is what I missed,I remeber it but I didnt read the text, it clearly tells how to read and I missed that instruction. I will try is as soon as I can. 
About the printf in the IRQ routine that is temporary I will not use printf's in IRQ's and you are right a few booleans allows for printing messages when the IRQ is left. 
Great help thanks for the tip.